# Safari (OS X) doesn't emit pointer events on overflowing SVG contents

Tags: css, svg, safari, overflow, pointer-events

I need to capture pointer events `click` and `mousemove` on shapes that are outside the contents box defined via `<SVG>` width/height, rendered via `overflow: visible`.

In this example, the `circle` is rendered properly, and current Chrome, FireFox and IE11 do capture pointer events on the overflowing part, whether or not there's e.g. `padding`. However, on Safari 10.0.1 OS X, pointer events are not registered, even when I use `padding`, `border`, and/or `margin`, no matter which ones of the possible 8 permutations.

Safari only emits click if it's inside the `<SVG>` contents block: https://jsfiddle.net/monfera/n1qgd5h4/5/

Is there a way of listening to pointer events that are in the overflow area? I haven't checked yet if Safari is non-compliant (bug) or the other browsers are lax.

I can resort to the workaround of making a larger `<SVG>` element but it would invalidate much of the benefit of the box model and the CSS `overflow`, leading to manually redoing in JS what the browser should do.

Comment: Safari is non-compliant.

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson, I filed bug report 29307386 with Apple

Comment: You may find the following polyfill useful. https://github.com/jquery/pep

Comment: @RobertMonfera could you please provide a direct link to this bug report you submitted? The issue is being discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566359/safari-doesnt-emit-pointer-events-on-overflowing-svg-contents) and it might be interesting to see webkit's response. (I couldn't find it in webkit's bugzilla)

Comment: @Kaiido I'm not sure if these things are public; url is https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=29307386 once logged in. Here's the main part, not much more info:

Steps to Reproduce:
Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587203/safari-os-x-doesnt-emit-pointer-events-on-overflowing-svg-contents and the linked jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/monfera/n1qgd5h4/5/

Expected Results:
It's expected that Safari registers mouse events on overflowing `paint` (or `all`); in this example, the padding, border or margin. 

Actual Results:
No pointer event is registered by Safari.

Comment: @RobertMonfera... "Don't have access" indeed. So did they respond? Is anyone working on it? If not, a better place would be https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: @Kaiido no answer yet... I'll check that site, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is still not fixed, over 2 years later. Pretty disappointing.

In case you need a quick fix:

```
svg {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 1000px;
   pointer-events: none;
   // don't use overflow here

   path {
      pointer-events: auto;
   }
}
```

`<path>` will then capture all mouse events. A little hacky, but it works in all modern browsers.